# How to add or remove items with variations in an Order Summary page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have created a model for an item with variations s,m and l, when I add the same item with the different variations from the product detail page (such as item1 size Small and item1 size medium) it correctly adds the quantity for each item with different variation to the order summary page using a post method in the product detail page.

Now in the Order Summary page when I try to add or remove the items with variations it is only updating to the 1st item added because it is reflected the item.slug not the item variations.

To reclarify Adding the same item with different variations is working fine except that in the template order summary.html there is a tag with href to add to cart and remove a single item from cart which I think is the reason for the issue of not updating the quantity to the variant but updating to the item.slug, the addition to the cart is not reading variations. I have drawn arrows in the views and template where I think the reason for the error.

I have also tried to add a post method in the order.summary.html template but it didn't work. (the reason I did this is that I have added the item variations from the product detail template through a post method, I have tried to do the same and it is illustrated below)

To better clarify here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

VAR_CATEGORIES = (('size', 'size',),)

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    objects = VariationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

Here is the views.py

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")

@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    item_var = []  # item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

        if len(item_var) > 0:
            for items in item_var:
                order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                    variation__exact=items,
                )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)  <------------- this line is not read in the template
        order_item.save()

    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")


@login_required
def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            if order_item.quantity > 1:
                order_item.quantity -= 1
                order_item.save()
            else:
                order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
```

here is the template which is causing the issues:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}
        <h2> Order Summary</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Item Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col">Size</th> 
                <th scope="col">Total Item Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for order_item in object.items.all %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                <td>{{ order_item.item.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ order_item.item.price }}</td>
                <td

                <a href="{% url 'core:remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></a></i>              <------------------------------issue is with this line
                {{ order_item.quantity }}
                <a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></a></i>                                     <------------------------------issue is with this line
                </td>                
                <td>
                {% if order_item.variation.all %}
                {% for variation in order_item.variation.all %}
                {{ variation.title|capfirst }}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                </td> 
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried to write a post method in the template instead of the `a href` but it didn't work, here is what I have tried

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
{% csrf_token %}
<a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></a></i>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your form action `action="{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}"`

`<form method="POST" action=".">` (if your  action is current page) otherwise
write like this  `<form method="POST" action="{% URL 'YOUR URL NAME ' PARAMS %}">`

I a'm also beginner I see many example. i hope this stuff work